# Limit apt-cache show results to only one record (the installation candidate)

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, apt-cache

Suppose I run `apt-cache show foo`- it prints out all records for `foo` . This is a problem if I want to use it from some kind of parsing script. Is there a standard way to show only the first record?

Comment: @steeldriver last version as in "highest priority + highest version", that is as you said, a candidate. `--no-all-versions` does the trick. Could you please post it as an answer so I can mark it as chosen answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `--no-all-versions` to limit the output to just the candidate version (i.e. the one that is/would be installed by `apt` or `apt-get`).

From `man apt-cache`:

> ```
>    -a, --all-versions
>        Print full records for all available versions. This is the default;
>        to turn it off, use --no-all-versions. If --no-all-versions is
>        specified, only the candidate version will be displayed (the one
>        which would be selected for installation). This option is only
>        applicable to the show command. Configuration Item:
>        APT::Cache::AllVersions.
> ```